# Leaflet tile edges show

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tile, boundary

I have a Leaflet map with custom tiles.  On my PC the map renders correctly.  On our Intranet site the edges of the tiles show as light gray.  There is a very small sliver of light gray around each tile at each zoom level.
I am wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue, and if they have, how they eliminated the tile edges showing.
I have tried resetting the map zoom after a zoom, and the tile edges still show.

```
map.on('zoomend', function () {
  var zoomlevel = map.getZoom();
  map.setZoom(zoomlevel);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried different browser, disabling 3d, using a canvas tile layer?..

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/3575 again.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else experiencing this issue, I just resolved it by resetting the zoom level in my browser. Was driving me nuts, turns out I was *very* slightly zoomed in.